# background attribute in CSS

Tags: css, background

```
background:#777777 none repeat scroll 0 0;
```

the 5 attributes it includes are background-color,background-image,background-repeat,background-attachment and background-position.

My question is:

Are background-repeat,background-attachment and background-position useless if background-image is none?
Because according to the document,these are all used to change background-image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. They have no meaning without that.

Comment: So it's a waste of code,right?
The same as background:#777777 none?

Comment: yes. If you just want to set the background color, you can just do background-color: #777777;

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write

```
background:#777777;
```

or,

```
background-color:#777777;
```

All of those attributes affect the image only.

In general, if a CSS attribute sets multiple values (eg, `background`, `border`, `font`), you don't need to specify all of the values; any values you don't specify will be left at their defaults.

Comment: oh,background:#777777;
this version is more compact than background:#777777 none

Answer (score 0):

IF you just want a background color, consider using the [background-color](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_background-color.asp) attribute instead of background.

Comment: Though keep in mind, background-color will not override a background-image set elsewhere...